# Symfony2 : How to get form validation errors after binding the request to the form

Tags: symfony

Here's my `saveAction` code (where the form passes the data to)

```
public function saveAction()
{
    $user = OBUser();

    $form = $this->createForm(new OBUserType(), $user);

    if ($this->request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bindRequest($this->request);
        if ($form->isValid())
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('success_page'));
        else
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('registration_form'));
    } else
        return new Response();
}
```

My question is: how do I get the errors if `$form->isValid()` returns `false`?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You have two possible ways of doing it:

- do not redirect user upon error and display `{{ form_errors(form) }}` within template file
- access error array as `$form->getErrors()`

Comment: I did the second thing you suggested but form->getErrors() return a blank array.

Comment: I also did the first one (w/ php templates  <?php echo $view['form']->errors($form) ?>) but still it's empty!

Comment: @mives You must set `error_bubbling` to true in your form type by explicitly setting the option for each and every field.

Comment: If you're using custom validators, Symfony doesn't return errors generated by those validators in $form->getErrors().

Comment: You can also do `$form->getErrors(true)` to include errors of child forms as well

Comment: Even after setting `error_bubbling` to `true` for each of my fields, both `{{ form_errors(form) }}`, `$form->getErrors(true)` and `$form->getErrorsAsString()` return nothing (empty array or string).

Answer (score 107):

Symfony 2.3 / 2.4:

This function get's all the errors. The ones on the form like "The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form." as well as additional errors on the form children which have no error bubbling.

```
private function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        if ($form->isRoot()) {
            $errors['#'][] = $error->getMessage();
        } else {
            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

To get all errors as a string:

```
$string = var_export($this->getErrorMessages($form), true);
```

---

Symfony 2.5 / 3.0:

```
$string = (string) $form->getErrors(true, false);
```

Docs:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.5.md#form
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#form (at the bottom: `The method Form::getErrorsAsString() was removed`)

Comment: This looks like most correct answer for current Symfony 2.4.

Comment: @Flip it Works perfectly on 2.5

Comment: Great answer BUT `$errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);` was throwing exception, as **getErrorMessages** was missing from **Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller** component. So i replaced it with `$form_errors[$child->getName()] = $child->getErrorsAsString();`

Comment: @AhadAli it's a recursive function, so when you put the code snippet in the class where you need this functionality it will be able to call itself. Your "fix" will prevent you to reach the nested forms. It worked for 37 other people, it should work for you too ;)

Comment: @Flip Ah sorry my bad, I was only looking at `$this->getErrorMessages()` and i thought its called directly inside a controller and part of Symfony api.

Answer (score 47):

Below is the solution that worked for me. This function is in a controller and will return a structured array of all the error messages and the field that caused them.

Symfony 2.0:

```php
private function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $template = $error->getMessageTemplate();
        $parameters = $error->getMessageParameters();

        foreach($parameters as $var => $value){
            $template = str_replace($var, $value, $template);
        }

        $errors[$key] = $template;
    }
    if ($form->hasChildren()) {
        foreach ($form->getChildren() as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
            }
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Symfony 2.1 and newer:

```php
private function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {      
    $errors = array();

    if ($form->hasChildren()) {
        foreach ($form->getChildren() as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
            }
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
        }   
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Improved https://gist.github.com/2011671 but still not what I want. I want array keys to be field names, but they are not.

Comment: @SalmanPK Twig isn't referenced anywhere in the above code. I don't believe I understand your comment.

Comment: Here is a fix for the previous gist, this works under Symfony 2.1.7. https://gist.github.com/WishCow/5101428

Comment: It looks like there is a typo `$this->getFormErrors` should be `$this->getErrorMessages` in your sample in Symfony2.1

Comment: @umpirsky To get the field name, I got this: $child->getConfig()->getOptions()['label']

Took me forever to find out...

Comment: This is by far the best answer here, many other answers are just wrong or are validating multiple times :). Collecting errors is complicated because forms are built like trees. If you want to know the "why" behind this answer or about form variables and doing more custom rendered, I've tried to say more here:  http://knpuniversity.com/blog/symfony-debugging-form-errors

Answer (score 36):

**Use the Validator to get the errors for a specific entity**

```php
if( $form->isValid() )
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    // get a ConstraintViolationList
    $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate( $user );

    $result = '';

    // iterate on it
    foreach( $errors as $error )
    {
        // Do stuff with:
        //   $error->getPropertyPath() : the field that caused the error
        //   $error->getMessage() : the error message
    }
}
```

API reference:

- [ConstraintViolationList](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintViolationList.html)
- [ConstraintViolation](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Validator/ConstraintViolation.html)

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a good approach to validate each entity separately. What if you have complex hierarchical form? The second problem is that validation happens twice.

Comment: @SlavaFominII - "The second problem is that validation happens twice" - Good point, nothing gets refreshed! Same error list after!

Answer (score 20):

To get proper (translatable) messages, currently using SF 2.6.3, here is my final function (as none of above's seem to work anymore):

```
 private function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {      
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form->getErrors(true, false) as $error) {
        // My personnal need was to get translatable messages
        // $errors[] = $this->trans($error->current()->getMessage());
        $errors[] = $error->current()->getMessage();
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

as the Form::getErrors() method now returns an instance of *FormErrorIterator*, unless you switch the second argument ($flatten) to *true*. (It will then return a *FormError* instance, and you will have to call the getMessage() method directly, without the current() method:

```
 private function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {      
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form->getErrors(true, true) as $error) {
        // My personnal need was to get translatable messages
        // $errors[] = $this->trans($error->getMessage());
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

)

The most important thing is actually to set the first argument to true in order to get the errors.
Leaving the second argument ($flatten) to his default value (**true**) will return *FormError* instances, while it will return *FormErrorIterator* instances when set to false.

Comment: Nice one, using the same stuff.

Comment: isn't it? :) @KidBinary

Comment: Absolutely gorgeous, mate : )

Comment: Better option is : 
$errors = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item->current()->getMessage();
}, $campaignForm->getErrors(true, false));

Comment: Good solution for Symfony 2.7

Answer (score 17):

For my flash messages I was happy with `$form->getErrorsAsString()`

Edit (from Benji_X80):
For SF3 use `$form->getErrors(true, false);`

Comment: I know it's an old answer but for future reference: `This method should only be used to help debug a form.` ([source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php))

Comment: getErrorsAsString() is deprecated in 3.0, use : $form->getErrors(true, false);

Answer (score 15):

The function for symfony 2.1 and newer, without any deprecated function:

```
/**
 * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form
 *
 * @return array
 */
private function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form)
{
    $errors = array();

    if ($form->count() > 0) {
        foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
            /**
             * @var \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $child
             */
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
            }
        }
    } else {
        /**
         * @var \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError $error
         */
        foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Comment: I was going to post a new answer to this post but you seemed to have beat me to the punch. I had to look through the source code to figure out why the method calls weren't found.

Comment: I've noticed this doesn't pull in errors from items that have error bubbling set to true. SF2.4

Comment: @stwe what is the purpose of the first `IF` statement? Why is it mutually exclusive? As far as I can see: form can have it's own errors as well as children.

Answer (score 5):

For **Symfony 3.2** and above use this,

```
public function buildErrorArray(FormInterface $form)
{
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        if ($form->isRoot()) {
            $errors['#'][] = $error->getMessage();
        } else {
            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $errors[$child->getName()] = (string) $child->getErrors(true, false);
        }
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

Use **str_replace** if you want to get rid of the annoying '**Error:**' text in each error description text.

```
$errors[$child->getName()] = str_replace('ERROR:', '', (string) $child->getErrors(true, false));
```

Answer (score 4):

### Translated Form Error Messages (Symfony2.1)

I have been struggling a lot to find this information so I think it's definitely worth adding a note on translation of form errors.

`@Icode4food` answer will return all errors of a form. However, the array that is returned does not take into account either **message pluralization** or **translation**.

You can modify the foreach loop of `@Icode4food` answer to have a combo:

- Get all errors of a particular form
- Return a translated error
- Take pluralization into account if necessary

Here it is:

```php
foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {

   //If the message requires pluralization
    if($error->getMessagePluralization() !== null) {
        $errors[] = $this->container->get('translator')->transChoice(
            $error->getMessage(), 
            $error->getMessagePluralization(), 
            $error->getMessageParameters(), 
            'validators'
            );
    } 
    //Otherwise, we do a classic translation
    else {
        $errors[] = $this->container->get('translator')->trans(
            $error->getMessage(), 
            array(), 
            'validators'
            );
    }
}
```

---

This answer has been put together from 3 different posts:

- [Symfony2 – Getting translated validation errors in controller](http://www.ens.ro/2012/11/14/symfony2-getting-translated-validation-errors-in-controller/#comment-33101)
- [How to use Symfony2 validator component without forms (Entities and data arrays)](http://www.ricardclau.com/2011/11/how-to-use-symfony2-validator-component-without-forms-entities-and-data-arrays/).
- [Symfony2 – Getting All Errors From a Form in a Controller](http://shout.setfive.com/2012/02/09/symfony2-getting-all-errors-from-a-form-in-a-controller/)

Comment: Just tried your version and it went `Fatal Error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Form\FormError::getMessagePluralization()`. I'm suspecting this is for Symfony 2.1 only?

Answer (score 4):

**SYMFONY 3.X**

Other SF 3.X methods given here did not work for me because I could submit empty data to the form (but I have NotNull/NotBlanck constraints). In this case the error string would look like this :

```
string(282) "ERROR: This value should not be blank.
ERROR: This value should not be blank.
ERROR: This value should not be blank.
ERROR: This value should not be blank.
ERROR: This value should not be blank.
ERROR: This value should not be null.
name:
    ERROR: This value should not be blank.
"
```

Which is not very usefull. So I made this:

```
public function buildErrorArray(FormInterface $form)
{
    $errors = [];

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        $errors = array_merge(
            $errors,
            $this->buildErrorArray($child)
        );
    }

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
        $errors[$error->getCause()->getPropertyPath()] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Which would return that :

```
array(7) {
  ["data.name"]=>
  string(31) "This value should not be blank."
  ["data.street"]=>
  string(31) "This value should not be blank."
  ["data.zipCode"]=>
  string(31) "This value should not be blank."
  ["data.city"]=>
  string(31) "This value should not be blank."
  ["data.state"]=>
  string(31) "This value should not be blank."
  ["data.countryCode"]=>
  string(31) "This value should not be blank."
  ["data.organization"]=>
  string(30) "This value should not be null."
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For **Symfony 5 and 6** I got this working :

```
public function getErrorMessages(Form $form) {
  
    $errors = [];        

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        foreach ($child->getErrors() as $error) {
                $name = $child->getName();
                $errors[$name] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

I got this kind of JSON thing with it :

```
errors: {
    firstname: "The firstname must be between 2 and 30 characters long.",
    lastname: "The lastname must be between 2 and 40 characters long."
    subject: "Please choose a subject."
    text: "Empty messages are not allowed."
}
```

It's nice and sweet enough for me, but I guess it will not pick up errors at the global level, like timed out tokens or other stuff like that.
Anyway, I've been quite a bit longtime looking for a solution suiting my case, and I'm happy contributing here hoping it'll help some developer somewhere sometime somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the validator service to get constraint violations:

```
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($user);
```

Comment: This will validate the object but not the form. If, for example, the CRSF token was the cause of the error the message wouldn't be included.

Answer (score 3):

### Translated Form Error Messages (Symfony2.3)

My version of solving the problem:

/src/Acme/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
services:
    form_errors:
        class: Acme\MyBundle\Form\FormErrors
```

/src/Acme/MyBundle/Form/FormErrors.php

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Form;

class FormErrors
{
    public function getArray(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form)
    {
        return $this->getErrors($form);
    }

    private function getErrors($form)
    {
        $errors = array();

        if ($form instanceof \Symfony\Component\Form\Form) {

            // соберем ошибки элемента
            foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {

                $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
            }

            // пробежимся под дочерним элементам
            foreach ($form->all() as $key => $child) {
                /** @var $child \Symfony\Component\Form\Form */
                if ($err = $this->getErrors($child)) {
                    $errors[$key] = $err;
                }
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

/src/Acme/MyBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($entity)->getForm();
$form_errors = $this->get('form_errors')->getArray($form);
return new JsonResponse($form_errors);
```

**In Symfony 2.5** you can get all fields errors very easy:

```
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form as $fieldName => $formField) {
        foreach ($formField->getErrors(true) as $error) {
            $errors[$fieldName] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using custom validators, Symfony doesn't return errors generated by those validators in `$form->getErrors()`. `$form->getErrorsAsString()` will return all the errors you need, but its output is unfortunately formatted as a string, not an array.

The method you use to get all the errors (regardless of where they came from), depends on which version of Symfony you're using.

Most of the suggested solutions involve creating a recursive function that scans all child forms, and extracts the relevant errors into one array. Symfony 2.3 doesn't have the `$form->hasChildren()` function, but it does have `$form->all()`.

Here is a helper class for Symfony 2.3, which you can use to extract all errors from any form.
(It's based on code from a comment by yapro on a related bug ticket in Symfony's github account.)

```php
namespace MyApp\FormBundle\Helpers;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;

class FormErrorHelper
{
    /**
     * Work-around for bug where Symfony (2.3) does not return errors from custom validaters,
     * when you call $form->getErrors().
     * Based on code submitted in a comment here by yapro:
     * https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/7205
     *
     * @param Form $form
     * @return array Associative array of all errors
     */
    public function getFormErrors($form)
    {
        $errors = array();

        if ($form instanceof Form) {
            foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
                $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
            }

            foreach ($form->all() as $key => $child) {
                /** @var $child Form */
                if ($err = $this->getFormErrors($child)) {
                    $errors[$key] = $err;
                }
            }
        }

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```php
namespace MyApp\ABCBundle\Controller;

use MyApp\FormBundle\Helpers;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function XYZAction()
    {
        // Create form.

        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            $formErrorHelper = new FormErrorHelper();
            $formErrors = $formErrorHelper->getFormErrors($form);

            // Set error array into twig template here.
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Symfony 3 and newer**

I recently made a function which creates a tree of form errors. This will be helpful for returning list of errors back to front-end. This is based on form types having:

```
'error_bubbling' => false
```

Code:

```php
public static function getFormErrorsTree(FormInterface $form): array
{
    $errors = [];

    if (count($form->getErrors()) > 0) {
        foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
            $childTree = self::getFormErrorsTree($child);

            if (count($childTree) > 0) {
                $errors[$child->getName()] = $childTree;
            }
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => This value is not valid.
        )

    [emails] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Given e-mail is not valid.
                    [1] => Given e-mail is not valid #2.
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Given e-mail is not valid.
                    [1] => Given e-mail is not valid #2.
                )

        )

)
```

**Notice**: I know that errors from deeper level fields can be overwritten if higher level has errors, but this is on purpose for my usage.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Jay Seth's answer, I made a version of FormErrors class especially for Ajax Forms:

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/FormErrors.php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

class FormErrors
{

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form
     *
     * @return array $errors
     */
    public function getArray(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form)
    {
        return $this->getErrors($form, $form->getName());
    }

    /**
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $baseForm
     * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $baseFormName
     *
     * @return array $errors
     */
    private function getErrors($baseForm, $baseFormName) {
        $errors = array();
        if ($baseForm instanceof \Symfony\Component\Form\Form) {
            foreach($baseForm->getErrors() as $error) {
                $errors[] = array(
                    "mess"      => $error->getMessage(),
                    "key"       => $baseFormName
                );
            }

            foreach ($baseForm->all() as $key => $child) {
                if(($child instanceof \Symfony\Component\Form\Form)) {
                    $cErrors = $this->getErrors($child, $baseFormName . "_" . $child->getName());
                    $errors = array_merge($errors, $cErrors);
                }
            }
        }
        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Usage (e.g. in your action):

```
$errors = $this->get('form_errors')->getArray($form);
```

Symfony version: 2.8.4

Example JSON response:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [{
        "mess": "error_message",
        "key": "RegistrationForm_user_firstname"
    }, {
        "mess": "error_message",
        "key": "RegistrationForm_user_lastname"
    }, {
        "mess": "error_message",
        "key": "RegistrationForm_user_email"
    }, {
        "mess": "error_message",
        "key": "RegistrationForm_user_zipCode"
    }, {
        "mess": "error_message",
        "key": "RegistrationForm_user_password_password"
    }, {
        "mess": "error_message",
        "key": "RegistrationForm_terms"
    }, {
        "mess": "error_message2",
        "key": "RegistrationForm_terms"
    }, {
        "mess": "error_message",
        "key": "RegistrationForm_marketing"
    }, {
        "mess": "error_message2",
        "key": "RegistrationForm_marketing"
    }]
}
```

The error object contains the "key" field, which is the id of the input DOM element, so you can easily populate error messages.

If you have child forms inside the parent, don't forget to add the `cascade_validation` option inside the parent form's `setDefaults`.

Answer (score 1):

For Symfony 2.1 onwards for use with Twig error display I altered the function to add a FormError instead of simply retrieving them, this way you have more control over errors and do not have to use error_bubbling on each individual input. If you do not set it in the manner below {{ form_errors(form) }} will remain blank:

```
/**
 * @param \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form
 *
 * @return void
 */
private function setErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {      

    if ($form->count() > 0) {
        foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                if( isset($this->getErrorMessages($child)[0]) ) {
                    $error = new FormError( $this->getErrorMessages($child)[0] );
                    $form->addError($error);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

$form->getErrors() works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution. It works solid with the latest **Symfony 2.4**.

I will try to give some explanations.

### Using separate validator

I think it's a bad idea to use separate validation to validate entities and return constraint violation messages, like suggested by other writers.

1. You will need to manually validate all the entities, specify validation groups, etc, etc. With complex hierarchical forms it's not practical at all and will get out of hands quickly.
2. This way you will be validating form twice: once with form and once with separate validator. This is a bad idea from the performance perspective.

I suggest to recursively iterate form type with it's children to collect error messages.

### Using some suggested methods with exclusive IF statement

Some answers suggested by another authors contain mutually exclusive IF statements like this: `if ($form->count() > 0)` or `if ($form->hasChildren())`.

As far as I can see, every form can have errors as well as children. I'm not expert with *Symfony Forms* component, but in practice you will not get some errors of the form itself, like *CSRF protection error* or *extra fields* error. I suggest to remove this separation.

### Using denormalized result structure

Some authors suggest to put all errors inside of a plain array. So all the error messages of the form itself and of it's children will be added to the same array with different indexing strategies: number-based for type's own errors and name-based for children errors. I suggest to use normalized data structure of the form:

```yaml
errors:
    - "Self error"
    - "Another self error"

children
    - "some_child":
        errors:
            - "Children error"
            - "Another children error"

        children
            - "deeper_child":
                errors:
                    - "Children error"
                    - "Another children error"

    - "another_child":
        errors:
            - "Children error"
            - "Another children error"
```

That way result can be easily iterated later.

## My solution

So here's my solution to this problem:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;

/**
 * @param Form $form
 * @return array
 */
protected function getFormErrors(Form $form)
{
    $result = [];

    // No need for further processing if form is valid.
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        return $result;
    }

    // Looking for own errors.
    $errors = $form->getErrors();
    if (count($errors)) {
        $result['errors'] = [];
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $result['errors'][] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    // Looking for invalid children and collecting errors recursively.
    if ($form->count()) {
        $childErrors = [];
        foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                $childErrors[$child->getName()] = $this->getFormErrors($child);
            }
        }
        if (count($childErrors)) {
            $result['children'] = $childErrors;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

I hope it'll help someone.

Comment: @weaverryan can you take a look at my solution please? Is it valid, or is there a drawbacks or any misconceptions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**SYMFONY 3.1**

I simply implemented a static method to handle the display of errors

```
static function serializeFormErrors(Form\Form $form)
{
    $errors = array();
    /**
     * @var  $key
     * @var Form\Form $child
     */
    foreach ($form->all() as $key => $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            foreach ($child->getErrors() as $error) {
                $errors[$key] = $error->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

Hoping to help

Answer (score 0):

**For Symfony 2.1:**

This is my final solution putting in together many others solutions:

```
protected function getAllFormErrorMessages($form)
{
    $retval = array();
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        if($error->getMessagePluralization() !== null) {
            $retval['message'] = $this->get('translator')->transChoice(
                $error->getMessage(), 
                $error->getMessagePluralization(), 
                $error->getMessageParameters(), 
                'validators'
            );
        } else {
            $retval['message'] = $this->get('translator')->trans($error->getMessage(), array(), 'validators');
        }
    }
    foreach ($form->all() as $name => $child) {
        $errors = $this->getAllFormErrorMessages($child);
        if (!empty($errors)) {
           $retval[$name] = $errors; 
        }
    }
    return $retval;
}
```