# number input and invalid message in Symfony 2

Tags: forms, symfony

I dont know if I understood it well... if i want an input of my form to receive numbers only, I can use a number field

```
$builder->add('width', 'number', array(
        'label' => $this->translator->trans('image.builder.width'),
        'invalid_message' => 'oops'
    ));
```

When I type letters in the input zone, the error occurs but the message does not display... there is nothing.

Is it the right way to use the number input ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you render the form errors

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

If you would like to display the form errors near their respective field see this question:

[Symfony2 form_errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655410/symfony2-form-errors)

Comment: sure i did that, the messages display well for any other errors but for this king of input... no

Comment: Could be related to either of these two bugs: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5707, https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2389