# Simple check if form field has errors in Twig template

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

In Twig template I check if a field has an error like this:

```
{% if form.points.get('errors') is not empty %}
```

Is there any method like:

```
{% if form.points.hasErrors() %}
```

to do it simpler? It's not a big difference, but if I can't do it easier why not.

Comment: Many answers have been added and some of them depend on the `error_bubbling` setting. I've added a PR to the symfony cookbook to improve the docs. Feel free to vote for it here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/6145

Comment: See my comment about how to do it with symfony 3.4, the dirty way through twig for&set or inside the controller :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49785276/7491491 Don't forget to upvote if it fix your needs :)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

That method does not exist. I typically do `{% if form.points.vars.errors|length %}`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me using Symfony 2.3. birko's solution with `form.vars.valid` works fine.

Comment: @binarious This method works fine in Symfony 2.3 but you're right, the birko's solution is better now.

Comment: When there is an error, this solution will produce `0` **IF** `error_bubbling` is set to `True` in form type.

Comment: Couldn't make this work. I want a per field treatment. Not treat all errors at once. How can I check if one field only is valid ? neither this nor form.MYFORMINPUT.vars.valid work.

Comment: Great, It Works!!

Answer (score 119):

better way I found, is to use this kind of code

```
{% if not form.vars.valid %}
<div class="alert alert-error">
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sadly this is not working for me, while calling `{{ form_errors(form.somefield) }}` still works.

Comment: @ex3v it depends on how you have set your error bubbling

Comment: could you expand your answer?

Comment: @ex3v as described here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-bubbling

default behavior has it set to be all errors displayed by the valid field. using form_row(form.field) or form_errors(form.field) wil display them.

if you set error_bubbling true for that field. the error will be displayed in his parent form.

Comment: Thanks! But things are getting complicated when you already have, say, 100 forms. I'm writing bundle to help resolve that, gonna share when it's done.

Comment: This worked for me when i used: {% if form.vars.valid == false %}

Comment: Note that in general, before testing the validity status you should also check if the form was submitted (like you would do in a controller), this can be done the same way with: `{% if form.vars.submitted %}`

Answer (score 18):

You can also check for errors when overriding field rendering:

```
{% block field_row %}
{% spaceless %}    
    <div class="control-group {% if errors %}error{% endif %}">
      {{ form_label(form) }}
      <div class="controls">
        {{ form_widget(form) }}        
        {{ form_errors(form) }}        
      </div>
    </div>    
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_row %}
```

Answer (score 14):

For deeper form customization I do:

```
<div class="form-group {% if form.MYFORMINPUT.vars.valid==false %}has-error{% endif %}">
//some twisted divs
{{form_label(form.MYFORMINPUT)}}
{{form_widget(form.MYFORMINPUT)}}
</div>
```

Sf2.5

Answer (score 4):

If you are using symfony version >= 4, you can check errors existence with this code

```
{% if form_errors(registrationForm) %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">        
        {{ form_errors(registrationForm) }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use :

```
 <div class="form-group {{ form.brand.vars.errors|length > '' ? 'has-error' }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of checking whether the form has an error:

```
{% if not form.vars.errors|length %}

{% endif %}
```

Symfony version >= 4

Answer (score 0):

Since an empty array resolves to false, you can shorten your existing check to

```
{% if form.WIDGET_NAME.get('errors') %}
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem, but `form.points` doesn't exist in my twig templates.

I had to get the number of errors in the controller, then pass it into my templates as a variable. `$form->getErrors()` does not behave as you might expect in your controller though. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978723/symfony2-how-to-get-form-validation-errors-after-binding-the-request-to-the-fo) for a function that will get the form errors correctly.

Answer (score -2):

i have create a twig extension to handle this:
my extension

```
public function hasError($string)
{
    if(strlen($string) > 4)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

i use it like this in twig

```
{{ has_error(form_errors(form.username)) ? form_errors(form.username) : '' }}
```