# Tables, forms and validation - Symfony2, Twig, Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have some questions all conected, so I will ask all of them here:

1. [Solved] I have date fields which can be nullable and when I don't fill them they are displayed as 2012-08-09 - today's date, although when I check in the database they are NULL. I have **@ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)** and **@Assert\Date** above both of them.
2. I have form validation **@Assert\Date** and **@Assert\NotBlank()** but I violate this constrains nothing happens although I have **{{ form_errors(form) }}**. How to show what exactly is wrong with the form?
3. [Solved] The last one is that I have NotBlank() constrain above a field called $currency. This is how I add it:

   ```
   $builder->add('currency', 'choice', array(
       'choices' => array(
           'empty_value' => '--- Choose ---', 'USD' => 'USD', 'HKD' => 'HKD')));
   ```

   but if I don't set anything (it stays --- Choose ---- ) it accepts it, although it's empty. I want the default choice to be --- Choose ---, but it musn't be allowed to leave it this way and the form to be valid in the same time.

I would appreciate your help!

Comment: Why do you have the string 'empty_value' for '--- Choose ---' it should be just '' if you want it to constrain against notblank

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I saw an example where it was 'empty_value' and I thought that it be this way. ;d

Comment: how do you display the date item?

Comment: This way **<td>{{ var.someDate|date('Y-m-d')}}</td>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, taken from the twig documentation:

If the value passed to the date filter is null, it will return the current date by default. If an empty string is desired instead of the current date, use a ternary operator:

```
{{ post.published_at is empty ? "" : post.published_at|date("m/d/Y") }}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me so much and answering on almost every question of mine! I appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0):

For the second question there is information here [Symfony2 : How to get form validation errors after binding the request to the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978723/symfony2-how-to-get-form-validation-errors-after-binding-the-request-to-the-fo) Sorry for not finding it earlier and questioning something that have been already questioned.