# I cannot get my form to be valid or be submitted. isValid() returns false

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I cannot get my form to be valid or be submitted. `isValid()` returns false. Using `PHP`, `symfony2` with entities - anotations, using `var_dump( $form->getErrorsAsString() );` which returns no errors.[symfony2 isValid() returns false without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19327722/symfony2-isvalid-returns-false-without-errors)

my code:

```
<?php

namespace Fishing\UsersBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class GetController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $users = new Users();

        $form =$this->createFormBuilder($users)
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->add('firstName', 'text')
            ->add('lastName', 'text')
            ->add('email', 'email')
            ->add('plainPassword','password')
            ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create User'))
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request); 

        if ($form->isValid()) {
        // perform some action...
            /*$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($users);
            $em->flush();
            */
        return new Response('isValid!');
        } else {

        var_dump( $form->getErrorsAsString() );
        //die;
        return new Response('notvalid');
        }

        return $this->render('default/userForm.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

my entities:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Users.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Email already taken")
 * 
 */
class Users
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $lastName;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Length(max = 4096)
     */
    protected $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_at")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $createdat;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="updated_at")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $updatedat;

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }

    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function getPlainPassword()
    {
        return $this->plainPassword;
    }

    public function setPlainPassword($password)
    {
        $this->plainPassword = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdat
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdat
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setCreatedat($createdat)
    {
        $this->createdat = $createdat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdat
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedat()
    {
        return $this->createdat;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedat
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedat
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUpdatedat($updatedat)
    {
        $this->updatedat = $updatedat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedat
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedat()
    {
        return $this->updatedat;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

My View :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}User Input{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    New User Input Form!
    {{ form_start(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        <br>
    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This may help you debugging http://stackoverflow.com/a/26504382/1507546

Comment: Please post your view?

Comment: I tried using var_dump( $form->getErrorsAsString() ); still no errors listed

Comment: If you add `{{ form_errors(form) }}` does it output anything?

Comment: Thanks to all, I found I needed to check !isSubmitted to load form if needed first, then persist data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you might consider dumping [`$form->getErrors()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.html#method_getErrors) instead.

[looking at the source](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/Form.php):

```
function getErrorsAsString($level = 0) {
    @trigger_error('The '.__METHOD__.' method is deprecated since version 2.5 and will be removed in 3.0. Use (string) Form::getErrors(true, false) instead.', E_USER_DEPRECATED);
```

My guess is that you might need to set your PHP error level to E_ALL.

Comment: i used var_dump($form->getErrors());  only to receive endless error codes. I have something wrong here, just dont understand it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your Form is not submitted in first place, look into html source code, if you have all components, especially the form-tag there.
2. When you want to submit data, ensure that this is valid (e.g. especially, when you have an  email field.). The form should be marked red, if there is smt wrong.
3. When this problem persists, I would suggest to separate the logic into two methods. First only displays the form, second handles the action and/or error. Of course you then have `$formbuilder->setAction($this->generateUrl('testform'))`