# Handle form errors in controller and pass it to twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to populate `$errors['field_name'] = 'Error message';` in my controller so that I can pass the variable to twig for further processing. How can I loop thru the errors and create my own array variable?

I've checked and applied these but didn't get the exact answer, or maybe I missed.

- [Accessing and Debugging Symfony Form Errors](http://knpuniversity.com/blog/symfony-debugging-form-errors)
- [Symfony2 : How to get form validation errors after binding the
  request to the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978723/symfony2-how-to-get-form-validation-errors-after-binding-the-request-to-the-fo) (Works but is it reliable?)
- [Symfony2 – Getting All Errors From a Form in a Controller](http://shout.setfive.com/2012/02/09/symfony2-getting-all-errors-from-a-form-in-a-controller/) (Overkill)

**FORM TYPE**

```
->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name', 'error_bubbling' => true))
->add('origin', 'text', array('label' => 'Origin', 'error_bubbling' => true))
```

**TWIG**

```
{% if errors is defined %}
    <ul>
    {% for field, message in errors %}
        <li>{{ field ~ ':' ~ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function submitAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new BrandsType(), new Brands());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() !== true)
    {
        $errors['field_name'] = 'Error message';

        return $this->render('CarBrandBundle:brands.html.twig',
                array('errors' => $errors, 'form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use validation?

Comment: Does it fall into second link I posted above? Sometime "validation" means/represents many different things person to person. I certainly get confused since I'm newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a method like this:

```
public function getErrorMessages(FormInterface $form)
{
    $errors = array();

    //this part get global form errors (like csrf token error)
    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    //this part get errors for form fields
    /** @var Form $child */
    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $options = $child->getConfig()->getOptions();
            //there can be more than one field error, that's why implode is here
            $errors[$options['label'] ? $options['label'] : ucwords($child->getName())] = implode('; ', $this->getErrorMessages($child));
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

This method will return what you want, which is associative array with form errors.

The usage of it would be in your case (controller):

```
if ($form->isValid() !== true)
{
    $errors = $this->getErrorMessages($form);

    return $this->render('CarBrandBundle:brands.html.twig',
            array('errors' => $errors, 'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

This usage assumes you have `getErrorMessages` method in your controller, however a better idea would be creating some class with this method and [registering it as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) (you might want to reuse it in other controllers)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll use it from now on.