# Symfony Form Error Rendering

Tags: php, json, symfony, error-handling

I have the following Problem. I use Symfony Forms to Validate a JSON Request, that also works great. But i will also the thrown Errors in a more Json readable way.

Is it possible that i can get from the FormErrorIterator FormError for each Error the relevant Field name.

For Example:

```
formName.SubForm.Propertyname => 'MyErrorMessage'
```

the structure of the path could be also an Array.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the errors of your form in an array you could add and use this method in your controller :

```
private function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) {
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        if ($form->isRoot()) {
            $errors['#'][] = $error->getMessage();
        } else {
            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
        }
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

$errors will contain an array of errors and if a field has an error the field name will be used as a key in the array :

$errors['FIELD_NAME'] = ERROR_MSG.

Depending of your Symfony version you might need or want other versions of this method : [Symfony2 : How to get form validation errors after binding the request to the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978723/symfony2-how-to-get-form-validation-errors-after-binding-the-request-to-the-fo/17428869#17428869).

**UPDATE**

If your [validation constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/validation.html) are on a field of the Entity class, they will be in the errors array with a key based on the field name.

If your validation constraints are on the Entity class, the will be in the # key or numeric key depending if the form is root or not.

**Entity class example**

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback("isValidName") <- this error will be in $errors['#']
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank() <- this error will be in $errors['firstname']
     */
    public $firstname;
}
```

If you want only errors on field, you need to move all your Entity class asserts on the Entity fields.

Comment: This seems more a comment. You need to request further information to those who asked the question if you want to extract from the reference link a more specific (and useful) answer to report here.

Comment: I have updated my answer regarding your comment, it should be more accurate.

Comment: in your answer you are writing from errors that are inside "#". how is it posible to bind one of this errors to a form field?