# Can't override FOSUserBundle ProfileFormType buildForm() function

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've been trying to override the ProfileFormType from the FOSUserBundle.  I followed the steps from my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475874/fosuserbundle-register-in-angularjs/31476270#31476270) problem which has been solved since my current task is somehow similar to the previous one. (I use AngularJS for frontend)

Unfortunately, I can't seem to override the buildForm() function from the parent class.

I've logged the form errors and it says:

> ERROR: This form should not contain extra fields.
>
> current_password:
>
> ERROR: This value should be the user's current password.

services.yml

```
services:
    acme.profile.form.type:
        class: Acme\BulletinBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType
        arguments: ["%fos_user.model.user.class%"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: acme_user_profile }
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    profile:
        form:
            type: acme_user_profile
```

ProfileFormType.php

```
namespace Acme\BulletinBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType {

    private $class;

    public function __construct($class) {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => $this->class,
        'intention' => 'profile',
        'csrf_protection' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'fos_user_profile';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'acme_user_profile';
    }
}
```

UserController.php

```
/**
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Route("/user/edit", name="user_edit", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->request->get('id');
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager()
            ->getRepository("AcmeBulletinBundle:User")
            ->find($id);

    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.profile.form.factory');

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();
    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
        return new JsonResponse(['valid' => true]);
    }
    $errs = (string) $form->getErrors(true, false);
    return new JsonResponse(['valid' => $errs]);
}
```

edit.html

```
<form class="form-group text-left" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate name="userFrm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user.email" class="required">Email</label>
        <input id="user.email" name="user.username" class="form-control" required type="text" ng-model="user.email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user.username" class="required">Username</label>
        <input id="user.username" name="user.username" class="form-control" required type="text" ng-model="user.username" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Update" ng-disabled="userFrm.$invalid"  class="btn btn-primary center-block col-lg-2" />
</form>
```

edit.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller('EditUserCtrl', ["$scope", "$http", "$state", "$stateParams", function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams) {

    //returns {username: data1, email: data2, enabled: data3}
    $http.get(Routing.generate('get_user', {id: $stateParams.id}))
                        .then(function (response) {
                            var user = response.data.user;
                            $scope.user = user;
                        });

    $scope.submit = function () {
                    var formData = {
                        fos_user_profile_form: $scope.user,
                        id : $stateParams.id
                    };

                    var success = function (response) {
                        var valid = response.data.valid;
                        console.log(valid);
                    };
                    var error = function (reason) {
                        alert('error');
                    };

                    console.log($scope.user);

                    $http.post(Routing.generate('user_edit'), $.param(formData), {
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                    })
                            .then(success, error);
                }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: i usually override the profile form in a different manner. Try extending the fosprofiletype form and call the `parent::buildForm` in the  buildForm method

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  It throws an Internal Server Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you extending profile form, but in your form template none of main fields exist. Remove this lines from your form type:

```
public function getParent() {
    return 'fos_user_profile';
}
```

or add missing field `current_password` to `edit.html`.

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  Turns out inheriting the ProfileFormType isn't necessary.